# Google container builder DockerFile with git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, google-container-registry

Our container-builder fail to build an image we have that has a private git submodule command as part of the DockerFile.

I linked the console account with the bitbucket account, (which has access to all repos) but still the build fail with "access denied" to the submodule repo.

in Quay.IO builder i solved this by adding the ssh-key to the submodule repository, but since Container-Builder link with my account i can't use that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Handling access to private submodules is a known deficiency of Cloud Source Repositories. We've added a feature request to them to add this support.

In the meantime, Cloud Builder is adding better support for the piping of keys / secrets, and will publish an example of how this can be done. This will likely be helpful for this use case.

The feature is likely to land in Q3. In the meantime, take a look at:

https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/tutorials/using-encrypted-files

to see if that solves the immediate issue.

Comment: That was the question, I'm using cloud builder and it fails. 
Do you know if the piping of keys / secrets exist already or what is the status of it ?

Comment: The feature is under development. We can update an ETA when we have a better idea.